# Configuring MSVC debugger in code::blocks

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I am using code::blocks. 
I set up the MSVC compiler(downloaded the MSVC Express 2010 Compiler and then added SDK directories).
The project does compile, however when I try to debug it ingores the breakpoints I set.
If I go Settings->Compiler->Toolchain Executables, the chosen Compiler is GDB/CDB : Default.
I guess the problem is gdb cannot debug msvc code. But how do I add a ne debugger?
In Settings->Debugger there is only one option of GDB/CDB compiler and I cannot add new one.
I tried adding additional directories, but it doesn't help.
So how do I make it work?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's in Settings/Debugger and not in in Settings/Compiler/Toolchain Executables.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem... I set path for cdb in code::blocks, ensured that the compiler added debug info, did everything I found on google (set Symbol Path to some weird stuff as described here: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,8454.msg63355.html#msg63355 and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and still nothing. I didnt have any errors in debuger log, but it still wouldn't work. Finally - EUREKA: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Path_with_spaces

> Breakpoints could not work if the path/folder you've placed your
>   project contains spaces or other special characters. To be safe use
>   English letters, digits and '_'.

After changing " " to "_" in directory names - everything works fine. And I lost only 5 hours for that...